# Enabling seccomp strict mode gets "Invalid Argument" error on Replit

Tags: c, linux, replit, seccomp

I am making an online code judge using Replit, and I want to use seccomp to securely run submitted code.

Through reading a few tutorials, I have made a simple test program to test seccomp:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <linux/seccomp.h>

int main(){
    prctl(PR_SET_SECCOMP, SECCOMP_MODE_STRICT);

    printf("Message #1\n");
    fork();
    printf("Message #2\n");
}
```

When I run the program, `Message #2` prints twice, which must mean seccomp didn't do it's job of stopping the fork. When I investigate using `strace`, I notice the following message within the output, though I am not sure what to do with it:

```
...
prctl(PR_SET_SECCOMP, SECCOMP_MODE_STRICT) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
...
```

How can I fix this problem, and get seccomp running in strict mode? I do not own a Linux machine, so I am not sure if this problem is specific to Replit, or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seccomp is already in use on replit. Make your program do `prctl(PR_GET_SECCOMP);`, or check `/proc/self/status`, and you'll see it's already active and in filter mode. While I don't see anything about that in `prctl`'s man page, I do in `seccomp`'s (which fails the same way if you try `syscall(SYS_seccomp, SECCOMP_SET_MODE_STRICT, 0, NULL);`):

```
       EINVAL A secure computing mode has already been set, and
              operation differs from the existing setting.
```

So if you want to use seccomp strict mode, you'll need to do so somewhere else. Setting up a Linux VM on your computer is easy and free, so that's what I'd recommend.